# Android In-App Purchases responsibility

Tags: java, android, in-app-purchase, in-app-billing

I am using Google Play In-App billing version 3.  I want to users to pay to unlock level packs in my game. This will be a consumable purchase obviously.

- If I consume these level pack purchases, am I responsible for tracking whether a level pack has been purchased, or can I rely on the billing API for this?
- If I can rely on the billing API for this and the device has no network connection, will the device have a local cache of purchases I can query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Personally, I think level packs are more suitable for managed (unconsumable) items.
You can create many sku(s) which correspond to each level pack.
Query items code looks like http://developer.android.com/training/in-app-billing/list-iab-products.html#QueryDetails or http://developer.android.com/training/in-app-billing/purchase-iab-products.html#QueryPurchases.

And yes, purchase items are cached locally by google play service, see description in above 2nd link.